# Php Image Up load not working

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to upload a image using PHP to a file, I am new to the langue so help is definitely appreciated. The image to be uploaded comes from a page with a from input, the code just doesn't seem to be executing! Thanks so much and here is my code (first html, second php): 
I am trying to upload a image using PHP to a file, I am new to the langue so help is definitely appreciated. The image to be uploaded comes from a page with a from input, the code just doesn't seem to be executing! Thanks so much and here is my code (first html, second php):

```css
<?php
    include_once 'Includes/dbh.inc.php';
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Tajawal|Quicksand|Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" tyle="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<!-- START Header -->
    
    <section class="headuser">
        <div class="pagetitle">
            C A T C H Y .
        </div>
        
        <div class="username">
            <a href="UserProfile.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></a>  
        </div>
    </section>          
<!-- END Header -->

<!-- START Bio -->
    <section class="Bio">
        <div class="friends">
            <br>freinds<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>  

        <div class="editbio">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>
            
            <form action="Includes/upload.php" id="bioimage" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="profileup">
                <button type="submit" id = "submit" name="upload">Use!</button>
            </form>
            <form action="Includes/Post.inc.php" id="bioform" method="POST">
                <textarea name="Text1" id= "content" placeholder="Tell everyone who you are" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Post!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section> 
<!-- END Bio -->
</body>
</html>
```

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $file = $_FILES['profileup'];

            $fileName = $_FILES['profileup']['name'];
            $fileTmpName = $_FILES['profileup']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['profileup']['size'];
            $fileError = $_FILES['profileup']['error'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['profileup']['type'];

            $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

            if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){

                if ($fileError === 0){

                    if ($fileSize < 1000000){
                        $filenamenew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                        $filedest = 'profileimages/'.$filenamenew;
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $filedest);
                        header("Location: ../UserProfile.php?suc");
                    }else{
                        echo "your file was to big";
                    }

                }else{
                    echo "There was an error uploading your file";
                }

            }else{
                echo "you cant upload files of this type";
            }
    }else{
        header("Location: ../UserProfile.php?fail");
    }    
?>
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Simple one. do not name button to **submit**. replace with other name because some times button with name **submit** not working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use your button name "upload".

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

when you submit an image it must be working.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
```

Answer (score 0):

problem for not execution of php script in upload page is tthis line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
```

because this check input submit is set in your html you have named submit button as upload

solution change name ofhttml buttton to submitt or change if condition to this

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
```